# Can dichotomous /binary data (0-1) be converted into Likert scale data (1-5)?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, likert, amos

Read somewehere that one can simply put 0's of binary to 1 of Likert and 1's of binary to 5 of Likert,Is it the traditional way?

Just for clarification,if someone is familiar with AMOS,i have the similar data like the one here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001457516300549 (you can access it via http://sci-hub.cc/ ) but can't figure out how the author converted the binary data for analysis in AMOS.
Thanks

Comment: You can relabel your 0's and 1's to any other two values (1 and 5 or 2 and 4 or 2.9 and 3.1 or 999 and 1000 or -55 and -42 if it suits you), but it won't alter their meaning in any way -- it's still only two different values, not 5. That is, it still won't actually be a 5 point Likert scale even if the values you convert to can be found on a Likert scale. It would be useful to explain what you want to achieve by doing this.

Comment: Well thanks for answering,i will look for some other suitable way.Actually i am applying SEM technique for the quantitative data.Normally we use likert scale data for the weightage in SPPS , however this time i have the data like the one in research paper mentioned above.No questionnaires!

Comment: It's not at all clear why you'd want to change the data rather than figure out how to do something suitable for the data you have.

Comment: Actually in the article mentioned above,the accident cases were assigned values of 0's and 1's.I was just checking whether there is a traditional way of converting such data to Likert scale that didn't come in my knowledge before. Now i have known that there isn't any,so i went with the same binary data on SPSS and analyzed it on AMOS. Results came just fine.

Comment: Some people have attempted to do such conversions before. To the extent that many of them did essentially the same things, you could argue there's a conventional way to do it, but the extent to which it has any meaning or particular value is more debatable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

I don't think it's the traditional way. It won't change your analysis or results in any meaningful way.

You probably shouldn't do it.

Comment: Yes,spot on.I just checked,it doesn't make any difference.Thanks!